# Arduino: static StringObject in class' method and main function

Tags: c++, arduino

I've got an existing program for AVR that uses a `main` function, and not a `setup` and `loop`. This seems to be needed as it makes use of timers and doesn't work when I manually replace it with `setup` and `loop`.

This works fine but I wanted to include some code from a library and now the compiler complains about multiple definitions of `main`. This is odd as nothing really is included and I declare my own `main` (so no sneaky default `main` function) and I've isolated to the following case:

```
int main()
{

}

// Foo.h
class Foo
{
  void bar();
};

// Foo.cpp
void Foo::bar()
{
  /* remove static here */
  static String foo;
}
```

The compiler starts complaining once I declare the `String` `foo` in the `bar` method. But only when it is declared `static`. Otherwise the code compiles.

I'm not a `cpp` guy and can't figure out why declaring a static variable inside a method would trigger this.

- It doesn't happen with other data types, (from what I can find) only with `String` (from `WString.h`?).
- When explicitly including `WString` nothing changes.

1. Is this a bug in the Arduino framework? Or am I missing something obvious?
2. If this is working as intended, what would be the best alternative?

My understanding (ignoring template classes) is that there is a single copy of `foo`; so I could declare it globally or as member variable for the class (the latter being technically different but there will only ever be a single instance of this class).

The error I'm getting:

```
// previous stages succeed
...
Linking everything together...
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p  -o "/path/to/build/static_in_cpp_method.ino.elf" "/path/to/build/sketch/static_in_cpp_method.ino.cpp.o" "/path/to/build/../arduino_cache_993247/core/core_arduino_avr_pro_cpu_16MHzatmega328_51f02b7210b938436b779d1c032618e1.a" "-L/path/to/build" -lm
main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `atexit':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
/path/to/build/sketch/static_in_cpp_method.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Pro or Pro Mini.
```

Comment: In C++ in is normal `string` not `String`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I realise that in plain cpp its `string` instead of `String` but it specifically happens with the `String` from `WString.h` on the Arduino platform.

Comment: @JakeFreeman Arduino doesn't have `string` but has [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/).

Comment: @justinvdk "*so no sneaky default `main` function*" [Yes there is](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/main.cpp#L33-L51).

Comment: @gre_gor Sorry, I wasn't really clear, but when you read the code you see that I declare my own `main`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't define your own `main()` function.
2. Add `void loop()` and `void setup()` functions
3. The code, that you wanted to place in `main()` function, should be separated into two parts:

   - initialization code should be placed into `setup()`,
   - and "main loop" code - into `loop()` function.

And your code would happily compile with or without `static` keyword.